# How to use database saved links of image to get images from laravel folder

Tags: laravel, image

I have saved images in 'public/images' folder in Laravel and the link/name is saved in MySQL database. All I want to get all images via API call. The problem is I can get a single image easily but couldn't get all the images.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I have no issue with single image however unable to get all at once.

Comment: Welcome! Can you please read about [the problems with images of text](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) and then [edit] to **add transcriptions** of your images of text as actual text? Perhaps useful: [/help/formatting](/help/formatting). See also [/editing-help#tables](/editing-help#tables).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead
Store the only image name and extension into database and then retrieve it by using DB and use asset to get image, refer the following code as practice.

```
$custom_data = array();
                        for ($i = 0; i <= $total_images; $i++) {
                            $image_name = $data[$i]->image;
                            if ($image_name != "") {
                                $image_with_path = asset('public/products/') . '/' . $image_name;
                            } else {
                                $image_with_path = "";
                            }
                            $custom_data['image'] = $image_with_path;
                        }
```